# Optimal Settings for Saving Photo take by iOS Camera (UIImagePickerController)

Tags: ios, camera, save, uiimagepickercontroller

The images I'm taking from the iOS camera via the `UIImagePickerController` class are way too large in size, and I'm having problems finding the optimal settings for saving. I need to get the image size on disk down to < 5MB. Currently, I'm at around 24MB.

Can someone explain (1) How to get the size down to less than 5MB but with still a good quality photo; or (2) Explain how Apple does it in the native camera app?

The images taken from the native camera app are all less than 5MB and yet very high quality (at least for what I need).

This is how I'm currently saving the images:

`[UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithImage:image 
scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(1000, 1500)], 0.4f) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO];`

Comment: Are you sure about the size? Are you talking about the size of the actual file on the disk, or some cache/NSData size? If the code you gave us is the only thing you're doing, a 1000x1500, 40% quality JPEG file should not be as big as 24MB.

Comment: @Altimor, good point. I don't actually know that it's that big on disk, I just assumed. When I monitor the memory consumed with VM Tracker in XCode Instruments, it jumps by 24MB when I load that image (using `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];`). My biggest concerns are (1) posting this image to a web server, which I will need to do, and (2) taking multiple photos quickly, which I haven't implemented yet.

Comment: You're addressing a very common misconception developers have when handling images. To quote Drew Crawford's excellent "Why mobile web apps are slow" :

    You often have the same photo in memory multiple places. If you are taking a photo, you have 1) The camera screen that shows you what the camera sees, 2) the photo that the camera actually took, 3) the buffer that you’re trying to fill with compressed JPEG data to write to disk, 4) the photo that you’re preparing for display in the next screen, and 5) the version of the photo that you’re uploading to some server.

Comment: @Altimor, when I'm taking the image, I don't see the Image IO footprint grow but by 1.83MB. That includes taking the image, choosing to use the image (rather than retake) and then load a preview of that image in an image preview listing (table view, if you will). However, launching a view that has a UIScrollView with the original image loaded into memory makes the Image IO footprint jump 20+MB. That after literally stepping over the call to `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];`. In this case, where are the additional images in memory?

Comment: @Altimor, I have confirmed, though, that the image on disk is actually between < 1MB to about 3MB in size. So, that is great. And I guess my question isn't a big deal now, since holding 20MB in memory isn't going to kill my app. However, I would still like to understand why loading that single image from disk is making Image IO jump. #confused.

Comment: @thephatp I have ran into same issue. Can you share your solution to it ? Thanks

Comment: @ila, is your problem that you're getting low memory warnings, or just that you're seeing the size larger than you'd like? If it's just the size, I found that the actual file size on disk was between 1MB and 3MB (open Organizer and download the app data, then view the documents you saved, and you should see the image file size) using the settings I specified in the question above. If you are getting out of memory or low memory warnings and size grows and never shrinks, set your images and image views to nil when you are done with them (don't know why this is necessary in ARC, but still is).